# При добавлении hover эффекта с задержкой, происходит наложение 2-х блоков друг на друга

Tags: javascript, jquery

[antonioli.eu](http://isaevrail-test.ru/works/antonioli/)

На этом сайте, при наведении на пункты меню "Мужское" и "Женское" появляется большое выпадающее меню, чтобы можно было переместиться на блок и он не пропал, я сделал задержку в пол секунды и теперь при наведении поочерёдно на эти 2 ссылки происходит наложение блоков друг на друга, за счёт чего начинает прыгать фоновое изображение из-за наложения блоков.

Как это можно реализовать, что бы при наведении не было наложение блоков, и чтобы можно было переместиться с ссылки на блок пока он не успел исчезнуть?

Вот как сейчас:

```
var men = $('.men'),
    timeoutId;

$('.men-link').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    men.show();
}, function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout($.proxy(men, 'hide'), 500)
});
men.mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    men.hide();
});


var woomen = $('.woomen'),
    timeoutId2;

$('.woomen-link').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId2);
    woomen.show();
}, function() {
    timeoutId2 = setTimeout($.proxy(woomen, 'hide'), 500)
});
woomen.mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId2);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    woomen.hide();
});
```

Comment: зачем так плодить код? надо одной функцией открывать/скрывать элемент.

Comment: В jQuery не  силён, использую чужой код.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var men = $('.men'),
    timeoutId;

$('.men-link').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    woomen.hide();
    men.show();
}, function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout($.proxy(men, 'hide'), 500)
});
men.mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    men.hide();
});


var woomen = $('.woomen'),
    timeoutId2;

$('.woomen-link').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId2);
    men.hide();
    woomen.show();
}, function() {
    timeoutId2 = setTimeout($.proxy(woomen, 'hide'), 500)
});
woomen.mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId2);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    woomen.hide();
});
```

Попробуй так